# How to calculate the dbHL in flutter?

Tags: java, flutter, audio, flutter-dependencies, playsound

I am new to flutter. I am using sound_generator to generate sound for different frequency and volume I want to find the dBHL of that frequency to plot that in line chart with frequency as x axis and dbHL as y axis. How to calculate the dbHL using the volume in sound_generator.

I can generate the wave tone for different frequency for different volume but i can't able to find the dBHL of that volume.

Comment: What does `dBHL` stand for?

Comment: If you are referring to "Decibel Hearing Loss", then you will have to have a calibrated output of each frequency. That is going to depend on both the device and the speaker that is being used. That is not a flutter problem, but very much a calibration problem. You are going to need access to instruments for calibration and probably a health professional specialising in audiology. If you do not, you won't be measuring dBHL, you will just be getting a number. Start with is an interface for generating  [Fletcher-Munson Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-loudness_contour).